# Force solib dependency to have relative path of non-standard named shared library under a directory using gcc

Tags: gcc, linker, relative-path, absolute-path, ldd

I have an issue regarding the linking of a shared library with a non-standard naming convention under several directories. I need the generated executable to search for the shared library within the executables current location, but cannot find a command line parameter to force this behavior.

To demonstrate this behavior all that is required is a shared library that is under a directory.

```
gcc -shared mylib.c -o some/dir/mylib.so

gcc main.c -o main -Lsome/dir -l:mylib.so
```

The executable **main** gives the following ldd output:

```
ldd main
     some/dir/mylib.so (0xf76e2000)
```

The output that I require is:

```
ldd main
     mylib.so => some/dir/mylib.so (0xf7700000)
```

This output can be created if the library is named conventionally as **libmylib.so** rather than **mylib.so** like so:

```
mv some/dir/mylib.so some/dir/libmylib.so
gcc main.c -o main -Lsome/dir -lmylib
```

This also drops the path **some/dir** in the ldd listing as required.

I have investigated the use of rpath, and command line options for both the ld and gcc but I am unable to find a satisfactory solution. The strict requirements of a non-standard name and directory structure cannot be changed easily in this case.

My question is how can I force the dependency of the library to be relative to the current directory rather than absolute as in the second ldd through gcc command line options.

Thank you for your time, I hope I have explained the problem reasonably.

Jon.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add [soname](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soname) in your shared library:

```
$ gcc -shared mylib.c -o some/dir/mylib.so -Wl,-soname=mylib.so
$ gcc main.c -o main -Lsome/dir -l:mylib.so
$ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=some/dir:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH ldd main
        mylib.so => some/dir/mylib.so (0x00007fa7a4fd6000)
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a magic variable you can pass to rpath to do this: `$ORIGIN`. See `man ld.so` for details.

I think in your case, the command should look like this (untested):

```
gcc main.c -o main -Lsome/dir -lmylib -Wl,-rpath,'$ORIGIN/some/path'
```

Note that you mustn't let the shell expand `$ORIGIN` as a shell variable.

BTW, this was the first Google hit for "rpath relative".

Comment: Thanks I appreciate the response, the command you specified will work however only if the library is named conventially as 'libmylib.so' whereas my is called 'mylib.so' in which case I have to use '-l:mylib.so'. This breaks the relative path created by ldd and forces an absolute path instead.

Comment: Right, I missed the colon. Does the `$ORIGIN` thing not work in your case?

Comment: Hi ams, it seemed to have no effect when the absolute library name is used (i.e. mylib.so). Jon.